# installshield :How to setup install conditions to determine adobe reader 9 or 10 is installed

Tags: installshield

My installation requirement is for the user to have adobe reader 9 or 10. I don't know how to setup an or condition. I am using install shield 2013

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With installShield 2013 you can create custom prerequisites within the Installation Designer.  Go to **Tools->Prerequisite Editor** and you can create a new custom prerequisite for your project.  If you have an installscript project you can search for it within the `OnAppSearch` function.

Answer (score 0):

use google or regedit to find the registry keys for adobe 9 and 10, then in your installer call these built-in functions to check if the adobe keys exist and that they also have the right values (version numbers):
**RegDBKeyExist() and RegDBGetKeyValueEx()**

if ( RegDBKeyExist(adobe9Key)=1 || RegDBKeyExist(adobe10Key)=1 ) then
 ...